# Can`t connect through ssh using passwordless technique to centos 7 as user but as root succeeds

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have been trying log in to my centos 7 using the passless technique.

First I have generated a public key:

`ssh-keygen`

then tried to connect keys with remote:

```
➜  ~ ssh-copy-id user@xxx.com
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
user@xxx.com's password: 

Number of key(s) added: 1

Now try logging into the machine, with "ssh 'user@xxx.com'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.
```

Also i tried with `-i`:

```
➜ ~ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@xxx.com
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/home/localuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
user@xxx.com's password: 

Number of key(s) added: 1

Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh 'user@xxx.com'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.

➜  ~ ssh user@xxx.com                             
user@xxx.com's password:
```

Later I tried to connect to remote but get password prompt:

```
➜  ~ ssh 'user@xxx.com'      
user@xxx.com's password:
```

Also, I tried did same with root user, and with root user, this technique works.

Output off `ssh -vv user@xxx.com`:

```
    ➜  ~ ssh -vv user@xxx.com
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "xxx.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to xxx.com [194.135.93.46] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/luser/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/luser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/luser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/luser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/luser/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/luser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/luser/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/luser/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to xxx.com:22 as 'user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:BTGZxt01OsYkDeXK5s7oH5R2m044Ioqbg7pph1r+4mM
debug1: Host 'xxx.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/luser/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /home/luser/.ssh/id_rsa (0x5577945c6c30), agent
debug2: key: /home/luser/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/luser/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/luser/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:1000)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:1000)

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/luser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/luser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/luser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/luser/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@xxx.com's password:
```

permisions:

```
[user@xxx ~]$ cd && while :; do ls -ld "$(pwd)"; test / = "$(pwd)" && break; cd ..; done
drwxrwxrwx 20 1001 user 4096 Aug 30 06:49 /home/user
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root 4096 Jan 30  2018 /home
dr-xr-xr-x 20 root root 4096 Jun 26 19:02 /
```

`.ssh` folder structure (just one file)

```
[user@xxx ~]$ ls -laZ .ssh
drwx------ uers  user ?                                .
drwxrwxrwx 1001 user ?                                ..
-rw------- user  user ?                                authorized_keys
```

from `tail -f /var/log/secure`

```
Sep  1 10:48:09 439986 sshd[29669]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/user
Sep  1 10:48:26 439986 sshd[29669]: Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 [preauth]
```

Comment: Try the `ssh-copy-id` again with `-i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to explicitly pass which identity file should be copied; by default the newest file is copied which might not be the correct one.

Comment: Please run this on the remote server, as the problematic user, and put the results into your question. It will list the directory permissions from your current directory up to the root of the filesystem: `cd && while :; do ls -ld "$(pwd)"; test / = "$(pwd)" && break; cd ..; done`

Comment: see updated post

Comment: Why does `/home/user` belong to `1001` and not `user`? Did you, by any chance, copy your own `/home/<name>` to the remote while preserving all user ids? Also, it looks like `/home/user/.ssh` is owned by `git`, whereas `/home/user` belongs to `1001`. That indicates an unsafe ownership, which is probably why OpenSSH refuses to accept the data in `.ssh`. Try to `chown` the `.ssh` directory.